# java card personalization script using smartcardio API

Tags: javacard, apdu

Hi i am writing a script to personalize java card using smartcardio API.

Following is the java code

```
    TerminalFactory tf = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
    List<CardTerminal> terminals = tf.terminals().list();

    CardTerminal cardTerminal1 = (CardTerminal) terminals.get(0);
    Card connection1 = cardTerminal1.connect("T=0");
    CardChannel channel = connection1.getBasicChannel();

    byte[] apdu = new byte[] { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0xA0,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x51,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00};
    String hex1 = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(apdu);
    System.out.println("Select Request : " + hex1 + "\n");

    ResponseAPDU respApdu = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(apdu));
    byte[] resp1 = respApdu.getBytes();
    hex1 = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(resp1);
    System.out.println("Select Response : " + hex1 + "\n");


     apdu = new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x9F, (byte) 0x7F, (byte) 0x2A};
     hex1 = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(apdu);
     System.out.println("Get Request with CLA 80 : " + hex1 + "\n");


     respApdu = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(apdu));
     resp1 = respApdu.getBytes();
     hex1 = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(resp1);
     System.out.println("Get Response with CLA: " + hex1 + "\n");



    apdu = new byte[] { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x9F, (byte) 0x7F, (byte) 0x2A};
    hex1 = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(apdu);
    System.out.println("Get Request with CLA 00 : " + hex1 + "\n");


    respApdu = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(apdu));
    resp1 = respApdu.getBytes();
    hex1 = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(resp1);
    System.out.println("Get Response with CLA 00: " + hex1 + "\n");


     apdu = new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x50, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08,(byte) 0xEC, (byte) 0xB9, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0xDF, (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x79};

    hex1 = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(apdu);
    System.out.println("Initialize Request Command : " + hex1 + "\n");


    respApdu = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(apdu));
    resp1 = respApdu.getBytes();
    hex1 = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(resp1);
    System.out.println("Initialize Response : " + hex1 + "\n");
```

Following is output

Select Request : 00A4040007A0000001510000

Select Response : 6F5B8407A0000001510000A550734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040215650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012A026E01029F6501FF9000

Get Request with CLA 80 : 80CA9F7F2A

Get Response with CLA: 9F7F2A53430019492170676001E7702B05718231581144729111447291114472912A0D000000000000006D00

Get Request with CLA 00 : 00CA9F7F2A

Get Response with CLA 00: 53430019492170676001E7702B05718231581144729111447291114472912A0D000000000000000000009000

Initialize Request Command : 8050000008ECB92711DF0F6179

Initialize Response : 6D00

If i send a command with CLA 00 i get proper response 90 00 otherwise card is returning 6D 00.

If any one has idea just let me know how can i resolve this issue using smartcardio API?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with smartcardio, 6D00 means that the command you are sending is not recognized by the card. Check your card/applet manual for correct coding of the command APDU.